# what is wrong with this C# duplicate row code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to duplicate a record in my database and I used this code you see below, the sql query worked perfectly in sql server but here I don't know what the problem...help me please

```
//Insert new Order
        int newOrderId = 0;
         if (e.CommandName == "Repeat")
         {
             try
             {
                 SqlConnection con = DataAccess.Connection.GetDBConnection();

                 //duplicate the jobs from the old order to the new added order
                 sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                 string com2 = "Insert Into [OrderItems] (orderId, productId, quantity, [length], note, multipleSlip, internalDiameter, " +
                     "wall, machineReCuttingId,winderId, jobNote)  (select @newOrderId, productId, quantity, [length], note, multipleSlip, " +
                     "internalDiameter, wall, machineReCuttingId, winderId, jobNote  FROM OrderItems Where orderId=@oldOrderId)";
                 SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(com2, con);
                 sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@newOrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newOrderId;
                 //assign the old order Id to the insert parameter @oldOrderId
                 sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@oldOrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                 sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 StatusLabel.Text = "The New Order is" + newOrderId.ToString() + " The Old order ID is: " + e.CommandArgument.ToString();

             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Response.Write(ex.ToString());
             }
             OrderGridView.DataSource = ViewDataSource(selectCustomer);
             OrderGridView.DataBind();
            // Response.Redirect("../Orders/AddNewOrder.aspx?customerId=" + selectCustomer + "&" + "orderId=" + newOrderId);

         }
```

By the way I tested the values of newOrderId and the oldOrderId they are both correct

Comment: Could you be a little more vague about what didn't work?

Comment: Did you get an exception?

Comment: Perhaps the orderId field is a unique value, and you are trying to insert again it with a "0" value after the first time it works from SQL server? Can you try again in the SQLServer (with the same values, as newOrderId=0) to see if this is the problem? (some more information about the error message should help).